# Authorization failure to Elastic Container Registry in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kops, amazon-ecr

I'm a complete loss. I have a kubernetes cluster running on ec2. I set it up using kops (versions 1.7.3/1.7.0 client/server). It's been working just fine for 4 months and all of the sudden I begin receiving this when creating new pods.

```
Failed to pull image "123456789.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
k8s-docker-s3-to-backup:latest": rpc error: code = 2 desc = 
unauthorized: authentication required
    Error syncing pod
```

I'm fairly certain I made no changes to the node or master roles in AWS IAM. There are no errors in my repo urls. I can create pods using public images.

I can't find anything helpful in cloudtrail. How can I further debug what is going on?

Comment: Hi, It seems that docker engine or daemon needs to have a credential to access the registry.  I have attached the link which will guide you.[reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Answer (score 1):

I can now confirm that nothing was wrong with my configuration. The IAM permissions listed in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-aws-ec2-container-registry) work. It does appear that either AWS was encountering an outage or perhaps I exceeded some sort of limit. I will check with my AWS rep and provide more info if I can get it. As of this morning, everything is working as usual.